# Access 2010 txt Search Box to Search multiple fields?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have multiple combo & text boxes to search for different values in my main table on my front end. The code is as follows, just replicated for different types etc. This all works fine.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.strSearch) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([tbl_Main.Description] Like ""*" & Me.strSearch & "*"") AND "
End If
```

My Problem is, I'm trying to create a text box which searches 2 columns simultaneously in my tbl_Main (`tbl_Main.LessonsLearnt` & `tbl_Main.RecommendedAction`) but can't figure out how to modify my current code to add another column in, searchable from the same textbox.

Disclaimer: I'm very much a beginner in MS Access - so please keep the explanation as simple as possible :D

If you need any other info - just let me know!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strWhere = strWhere & "(tbl_Main.Description Like '*" & Me.strSearch & "*' OR tbl_Main.OtherField Like '*" & Me.strSearch & "*') AND "
```

This will search for the `strSearch` being in either `Desscription` or `OtherField`. I also replaced your double double quotes with single quotes for better code readability and cross compatibility with other DBMS and removed the brackets that are only needed if you have spaces in your table/field names (something you really should never do anyway).